# Failure for parallel - parallel two-port network

Tags: circuit-analysis, parallel, network

I'd like to know what's the simplest example of two-port parallel-parallel network that fails Y=Ya+Yb.
Just as two T networks fail series-series connection, I thought that two Pi network would fail parallel-parallel, but it isn't true.
Could you help me giving a simple example?

Comment: How about an example of "failure"?

Comment: @analogsystemsrf i'm referring to this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brune_test

Comment: @Surferonthefall I think you should try to answer this by yourself based on the examples for series fails, and figuring when a potential difference will be created in the parallel configurations. It is not difficult at all. BTW, the T networks DO NOT fail series-series connections ALWAYS. Look carefully at the examples/